Conditional median of $X+Y$ given $Z=z$
I have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, where $Y$ is also independent of $Z$, and $E(X\mid Z=z)=0$ for any $z$. We also know that the conditional distribution of $X+Y$ given $Z=z$ is symmetric about some $\delta(z)$ for any $z$. Now I am curious about whether we can conclude that $\delta(z)$ is a constant independent of $z$. When $E(|Y|)<+\infty$, I find that $E(X+Y\mid Z=z)=E(X\mid Z=z)+E(Y\mid Z=z)=E(Y)$ because $Y$ is independent of $Z$. Then $\mathrm{Med}(X+Y\mid Z=z)=E(Y)$ because the conditional distribution of $X+Y$ given $Z=z$ is symmetric. So in this case we can conclude that the conditional distribution of $X+Y$ given $Z=z$ is symmetric about the same constant for any $z$. But when $E(|Y|)=+\infty$, I have no idea how to prove this statement (or whether this statement is true), because in this case we cannot take expectation and use its linearity.

Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so,
please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its
wiki.
